# filter MySQL table based on a condition

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm struggling with this. I want to filter table results with a condition within one field driving the results for other fields. A simple version of what I'm trying to do:

ORGView FIELDS and VALUES

```
org_name, revenue, costs, year
org_w, 50, 40, 2020
org_w, 60, 50, 2021
org_x, 20, 10, 2020
org_x, 100, 80, 2021
org_y, 50, 40, 2020
org_y, 120, 100, 2021
```

I want to run a query which filters all the above table view where the revenue in year 2021 is between 100 to 500

As an example it would return the following result (i.e. excluding org_w as its revenue in 2021 was outside the range)

```
org_name, revenue, costs, year
org_x, 20, 10, 2020
org_x, 100, 80, 2021
org_y, 50, 40, 2020
```

If anyone can help I would be really grateful.

I tried putting the years into columns but failed ... i.e. max(case when year = 2021 then revenue end) AS 2021

Answer (score 0):

You can  check with `EXISTS`if one or more conditions are valid for one org_name.

```
CREATE TABLE Tablen
(`org_name` varchar(5), `revenue` int, `costs` int, `year` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO Tablen
    (`org_name`, `revenue`, `costs`, `year`)
VALUES
    ('org_w', 50, 40, 2020),
    ('org_w', 60, 50, 2021),
    ('org_x', 20, 10, 2020),
    ('org_x', 100, 80, 2021),
    ('org_y', 50, 40, 2020),
    ('org_y', 120, 100, 2021)
;
```

```
SELECT `org_name`, `revenue`, `costs`, `year`
FROM Tablen tn
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Tablen WHERE `org_name` = tn.`org_name` 
  AND `revenue` BETWEEN 100 AND 500 AND `year` = 2021)
```

| org_name | revenue | costs | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| org_x | 20 | 10 | 2020 |
| org_x | 100 | 80 | 2021 |
| org_y | 50 | 40 | 2020 |
| org_y | 120 | 100 | 2021 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_ozvsowE)